# Getting closest possible destination - Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, navmesh

I'm trying to understand how to get the closest to a destination with Unity's navigation system when a Nav Mesh Obstacle is in the way.
I have this example with a Capsule obstacle (with Carve on) and a capsule agent managed with a script. It seems to work okish, but when I "click" on the obstacle to set the destination of the agent (to a point inside the carved area), the agent moves to another location around the obstacle.

**How can I make the agent go to the closest point around the obstacle or to the closest point to the selected destination (that is inside the area of the obstacle)?**

[image: Snap]

**Script to move the agent**

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class CapsuleMovement : MonoBehaviour {
    NavMeshAgent agent;
    public NavMeshPathStatus partial;

    void Start() {
        agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
    }

    void Update() {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
            RaycastHit hit;

            if (Physics.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition), out hit, 100)) {
                agent.destination = hit.point;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried https://docs.unity3d.com/540/Documentation/ScriptReference/NavMesh.SamplePosition.html ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Take the center of the clicked objects position and move it slightly towards the moving unit/player, then use that position as your coordinate instead of the direct mouse click.**

---

If that doesn't work.

This is not a guaranteed answer as that is hard to give in a situation such as this, but I hope this brings you further.

I suspect that it may be the coordinate you click, which something is not working out as it should with. Try spawn a "ClickObject" which can just be a coloured sphere, at the position of the mouse click. That way you can confirm where the click actually is happening.

---

Here is furthermore 2 methods that may come in handy when working with NavMeshes and positioning.

You could try use SamplePosition.

https://docs.unity3d.com/540/Documentation/ScriptReference/NavMesh.SamplePosition.html

> Finds the closest point on NavMesh within specified range.

Perhaps also FindClosestEdge

https://docs.unity3d.com/530/Documentation/ScriptReference/NavMesh.FindClosestEdge.html

> Locate the closest NavMesh edge from a point on the NavMesh.

Comment: Thank you. You were right, my click was not on the terrain, but on the object. Setting the position to the center of the obstacle object, made the agent move to the closest edge of the obstacle.